# Amplifier limiter using LM13700

Tags: amplifier, ota, automatic-gain-control

Does someone has the knowledge of a schematic for a audio limiter circuit using LM13700? I found one on the internet, but it has the limitation that is not adequate for audio signals with a lot of low frequency content.If someone has any tips, documents, I would really appreciate it.[image]

Comment: Hi! There's a relatively logical rule that requires you to cite your sources when you quote someone else's schematic. Please do add a link to where you found it and name the author. Stupid question: why would you base a limiter design on an ota developed in the 1970s? That just seems unnecessary low-fi and hard (especially seeing the supply voltage needs) to me.

Comment: " it has the limitation that is not adequate for audio signals with a lot of low frequency content" - why do you think this? I can tell you from memory it is a kind of hobbyist level compressor/limiter from about 20 years ago because LM13700 is not a very good VCA (lots of distortion). I think if you will hunt around you will find better circuits - look for ones using SSM2120 or the modern equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value of 'C5' , this seems to roll of the low frequency response.